# bluetooth mouse dies

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, drivers

I have a Dell Bluetooth mouse/keyboard combo.  They DO work independently of each other.  It's all made by Logitech, including the supplied Bluetooth adapter.  It has worked fine for 2 years now.

Windows 7, 6GB ram, 2TB drive... all the updates.

A few days ago the computer made an error sound, the one it makes when an application dies, usually a popup stating it's gathering info to send to M$ would accompany that sound.  When it happened the mouse stopped working.  Keyboard was fine.  I tried to re-establish the connection but setpoint never could find the mouse.

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers says the device has trouble, but troubleshooting can not find the solution.

Device manager shows no devices with errors...
Rebooting it fixed the problem, but 2 hours later it happened again.   I'm a programmer with a lot of apps open, I usually reboot about once very two weeks, so this is going to become a major pain.

Any ideas?